# Scoping issue with using function to add rows to data frame?

Tags: r, function, scoping

I wonder if this might be a scoping problem.  I am new to R and am trying to use a function on a series of columns and outputing the results to a new data frame.  The function should add the results in a new row.

Below is a simplified version of the code.  Currently, the function does not add any data to the ouput data frame ("pinecone").  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?  Many thanks in advance!

```
## create random data frame
honeybadger <- data.frame(alpha = sample(20:35,100, replace=T),
                      beta = sample(1:35,100, replace=T),
                      gamma = sample(200:301,100, replace=T),
                      delta = sample(40:100,100, replace=T), 
                      epsilon = sample(10:45,100, replace=T))

## create empty data frame for results
pinecone <- data.frame("col_A" = numeric(),
                   "col_B" = numeric(),
                   "col_C" = numeric(),
                   "col_D" = numeric())

## define function to analyze data and add to results data frame
funkytown <- function(greek,rand_int) {
  parameter <- deparse(substitute(greek))
  pinecone[parameter,] <- list("col_A" = mean(greek),
                     "col_B" = rand_int+3,
                     "col_C" = sd(greek),
                     "col_D" = rand_int)
}

## run function on data columns
funkytown(honeybadger$alpha,2)
funkytown(honeybadger$beta,5)
funkytown(honeybadger$gamma,4)
funkytown(honeybadger$delta,1)
funkytown(honeybadger$epsilon,9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you goal is here. Maybe this:

```
set.seed(42)
honeybadger <- data.frame(alpha = sample(20:35,100, replace=T),
                          beta = sample(1:35,100, replace=T),
                          gamma = sample(200:301,100, replace=T),
                          delta = sample(40:100,100, replace=T), 
                          epsilon = sample(10:45,100, replace=T))

numbers <- sample.int(20, 5)

t(mapply(function(x,y) data.frame(
  col_A=mean(x),
  col_B = y+3,
  col_C = sd(x),
  col_D = y
  ), honeybadger, numbers))

#        col_A col_B col_C    col_D
#alpha   27.92 6     4.751778 3    
#beta    18.69 7     9.91244  4    
#gamma   244.5 13    29.22138 10   
#delta   70.19 17    18.09609 14   
#epsilon 26.08 5     10.5569  2
```

Comment: Thank you, Roland!  That does indeed look much more efficient.  If you have a second, the step in what you do that I don't understand is why the create the random sample (sample.int)?  I want to analyze the full data set, of course, rather than a sample from it.   At any rate, thanks again.  This helps me to code much more R-ish-ly, as jolan puts it below.

Comment: @Leef I've used `sample_int` to create some values for your `rand_int` variable. I was too lazy to copy them from your question.

Comment: Nevermind.  I see that you were just replicating the "rand_int" step I included in my example.  I think I get it now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of going about this all wrong.

1. Creating an empty data frame and then filling it is a very bad design pattern in R. For *very* small numbers of rows, it's probably not a huge deal, but this will not scale. Every time you add a row, R is forced to copy the entire data frame. This will become *very* slow.
2. In general, modifying objects that are defined outside of a function (e.g. `pinecone` being modifies from within `funkytown`) is again not something we generally do in R, unlike in other languages. If you want to modify something, pass it (i.e. `pinecone`) as an argument, and then return it and capture the return value. (You *can* do it using `<<-` or `assign`, but you'll be sorry down the road.)
3. `deparse(substitute(greek))` clearly doesn't do what you think it does. It results in a character `"honeybadger$alpha"`.

See Roland's answer for a more R-ish way of approaching what might be your end goal.

Comment: Thanks for the input, joran--much appreciated.  With regard to your point #2, passing pinecone as an argument and returning it makes sense, but waht about "capture the return value"?  I'm not sure what this entails.  (And with regard to #3, I actually did want to create a character string like that.  My naming scheme contains all the info I need to identify what the data means and so it seemed an easier way to mark what the row shows then to go through and name them all ahead of time.)

Comment: @Leef Sorry about the confusion; I just meant that if you modify an object in a function and want to keep the changes, you need to return the value from the function _and_ assign the result. So if `foo()` modifies `bar`, you'd need to do `bar <- foo(bar)`. I apologize if that's insultingly basic, habit just has me mentioning things like that cause it's a common mistake for R beginners.

Comment: @ joran: no worries, it's definitely not insulting—it helps to have things spelled out particularly explicitly when you're still developing an understanding of how to use the language.  I get what you mean.  Thanks!